# How do I turn a Scala case class into a mongo Document

Tags: mongodb, scala

I'd like to build a generic method for transforming Scala Case Classes to Mongo Documents.

A promising [Document constructor](http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/2.8/scaladoc/index.html#org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document$) is

```
fromSeq(ts: Seq[(String, BsonValue)]): Document
```

I can turn a case class into a Map[String -> Any], but then I've lost the type information I need to use the implicit conversions to BsonValues. Maybe TypeTags can help with this?

Here's what I've tried:

```
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonTransformer
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonValue

case class Person(age: Int, name: String) 

//transform scala values into BsonValues
def transform[T](v: T)(implicit transformer: BsonTransformer[T]): BsonValue = transformer(v)

// turn any case class into a Map[String, Any]
def caseClassToMap(cc: Product) = { 
  val values = cc.productIterator
  cc.getClass.getDeclaredFields.map( _.getName -> values.next).toMap
}

// transform a Person into a Document
def personToDocument(person: Person): Document = {  
  val map = caseClassToMap(person)

  val bsonValues = map.toSeq.map { case (key, value) =>
    (key, transform(value))
  }

  Document.fromSeq(bsonValues)
}

<console>:24: error: No bson implicit transformer found for type Any. Implement or import an implicit BsonTransformer for this type.
           (key, transform(value))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def personToDocument(person: Person): Document = {  
    Document("age" -> person.age, "name" -> person.name) 
}
```

Comment: This sucks as a practical solution. I can imagine doing this only if I'm paid by the hour.

Answer (score 1):

Below code works without manual conversion of an object.

```
import reactivemongo.api.bson.{BSON, BSONDocument, Macros}

case class Person(name:String = "SomeName", age:Int = 20)

implicit val personHandler = Macros.handler[Person]

val bsonPerson = BSON.writeDocument[Person](Person())

println(s"${BSONDocument.pretty(bsonPerson.getOrElse(BSONDocument.empty))}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to serialize a case class to a BsonDocument using the org.bson.BsonDocumentWriter. The below code runs using scala 2.12 and mongo-scala-driver_2.12 version 2.6.0

My quest for this solution was aided by this answer (where they are trying to serialize in the opposite direction): [Serialize to object using scala mongo driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33967099/serialize-to-object-using-scala-mongo-driver)

```
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.Macros
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.codecs.DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistries.{fromRegistries, fromProviders}
import org.bson.codecs.EncoderContext
import org.bson.BsonDocumentWriter
import org.mongodb.scala.bson.BsonDocument
import org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecRegistry
import org.bson.codecs.Codec

case class Animal(name : String, species: String, genus: String, weight: Int)

object TempApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val jaguar = Animal("Jenny", "Jaguar", "Panthera", 190)

    val codecProvider = Macros.createCodecProvider[Animal]()
    
    val codecRegistry: CodecRegistry = fromRegistries(fromProviders(codecProvider), DEFAULT_CODEC_REGISTRY)

    val codec = Macros.createCodec[Animal](codecRegistry)

    val encoderContext = EncoderContext.builder.isEncodingCollectibleDocument(true).build()

    var doc = BsonDocument()

    val writr = new BsonDocumentWriter(doc) // need to call new since Java lib w/o companion object

    codec.encode(writr, jaguar, encoderContext)

    print(doc)

  }

};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use Salat https://github.com/salat/salat. A nice example can be found here - https://gist.github.com/bhameyie/8276017. This is the piece of code that will help you -

```
import salat._

val dBObject = grater[Artist].asDBObject(artist)
artistsCollection.save(dBObject, WriteConcern.Safe)
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)